# How to prove this is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Let $F=(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]/(x^2+2x+3)$. How do I prove $F$ is a field?

I've shown its a commutative ring with an identity $\bar1$. Then we let $(\bar{a}x+\bar{b})^{-1}=(\bar{c}x+\bar{d}).$ Multiplying those together gives me and substituting $3x+2$ for $x^2$ gives me the following two equations...not sure what to do next.

$\bar{3ac}+\bar{ad}+\bar{ac}=\bar0$

$\bar{2ac}+\bar{ad}=\bar1$

I also need to prove that every element can be written as $\bar{a}x+\bar{b}$, although I feel like I already proved that somewhat.

Comment: Maybe $F$ is not a field. Are you sure that it is ok?

Comment: I messed up, it should be a 5 instead of 2

Comment: In this case, you can use the same method: plug in numbers to the polynomial, and show that it has no roots.  Then it must be irreducible, so the quotient is a field.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+2x+3$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, so it is irreducible.  Therefore $(x^2+2x+3)$ is maximal, so $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+2x+3)$ is a field.

Comment: I screwed up, it should have been 5 instead of 2

Comment: OK, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Is $f(x) = x^2 + 2x  +3$ irreducible in $\mathbb Z /5 \mathbb Z[x]$?

Comment: I screwed up...it should have been 5 instead of 2

Comment: In any case, a good way to answers this is by checking if $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5$. Then you may conclude that the ideal generated by $f$ is maximal, and therefore the quotient $\mathbb Z_5[x]/ \langle f \rangle$ is going to be a field.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$ we have $x^2 + 2x + 3$ = $x^2+1$, so $x + 1 \neq 0$ and (in the quotient) $(x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1 = 2x = 0$. But in a field there are no zero divisors, a contradiction.

Comment: I screwed up, it should have been 5 instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic $f$ has no roots in the field $\,\Bbb Z_5\,$ so it is irreducible. So, by Bezout

$\qquad\qquad\quad\ \  f\nmid g\ \Rightarrow\  a\, f + b\, g\, =\, 1\ \ {\rm for}\ \ a,b \in \Bbb Z_5[x]$

So $\ {\rm mod}\ f\!:\ g\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, a(0)+ bg\equiv 1,\,$ i.e. $\  g^{-1}\equiv 1$