# Characteristic of a field extension of this form

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

[How to prove this is a field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242271/how-to-prove-this-is-a-field)

Following this post, how would one calculate the characteristic of F?

Let $F=(\Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z)[x]/(x^2+2x+3)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please check [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to learn how to format mathematics using MathJax (don't forget to check links at the bottom for detailed guides).

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic of a field determines [the prime subfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#Case_of_fields) (and vice versa), which is either $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. So which of these is contained in your $F$?

Comment: Does downvoter care to explain why they downvoted both this and Stefan4024's answer?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Take the identity element in $F$, which is obviously $1$. Keep adding it to itself for a little bit. Eventually it will become $0$ and the number of times you've added $1$ in order to get $0$ is the charactersitic of the field.

---

Actually you can see easily see that the characteristic is $p$. Assume that the characteristic is finite and it's $n$. Then as $[n] \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ we have that $[n][1] = [0]$, but as we're working in a field we must have $[n] = [0]$ or $[1] = [0]$. The latter is impossible, so we have that $[n] = [0]$. Now the charactersitic is the smallest positive integer of $[0]$, which is $p$.

Comment: And what if the characteristic of $F$ were $0$?

Comment: @Ennar Well the field is finite, so it can't be of a charactersitic $0$.

Comment: @Ennar On the other side we can assume that $F$ has a finite characteristic. Once we find a possible candidate we can verify whether this is true or not afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is not visible in your answer.

Comment: @Ennar After all the OP can do some little bit of calculaton on his own :). And more or less it's trivial. BTW I didn't upvoted, then downvoted your answer, so don't misunderstand it as a revenge vote or something.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to suggest that you could add that characteristic is not $0$, so you are not sending OP on a goose chase. And I know you didn't downvote, the same person probably downvoted both of our answers for no good reason.